# ajax reload causes jquery issues

Tags: ajax, javascript, views

i jquery applied to a exposed filter to force the look of a drop down with checkboxes which works fine until the ajax reloads the content and cause the slideToggle to open and close immediately. i switched it to just css height and the box wont open after ajax reload. Anyone have any ideas or options that might work after ajax reload. 
 just css option

```
boxes1.css({"display" : "none", "background": "#f2f2f2", "border" : "1px solid #ccc", "padding":"5px", "margin-top" : "25px","position":"absolute","overflow" : "hidden"});
    title.live("click",function(){
        if(boxes1.is(":hidden")){       
            boxes1.css({"height" : "300", "display" : "block"});
        } 
        else {
            boxes1.css({"display" : "none"});
        }
    });
```

slideToggle option

```
boxes1.css({"display" : "none", "background": "#f2f2f2", "border" : "1px solid #ccc", "padding":"5px", "margin-top" : "25px","position":"absolute","overflow" : "hidden"});
    title.live("click",function(){      
            boxes1.slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might have to do with behaviours

see [jquery script on view not working when filtering with (ajax on) 'better_exposed_filters' module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/jquery-script-on-view-not-working-when-filtering-with-ajax-on-better-exposed/129643#129643)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the similar issue and was able to resolve :)  I came across this post while searching.  I realize it's been a bit since your post, and this is not the entire answer to your puzzle, but...

In my case, it was a field that updating via ajax and showing briefly.  I ended up enclosing the field in a div and setting the div to {display:none}.  In your example, the jQuery should then act upon the div $('#yourdivid').find('.myclass').

Don't know if it will work for you, but if you're still stuck, it may point you in the right direction!

KMT