# jquery script on view not working when filtering with (ajax on) 'better_exposed_filters' module

Tags: ajax, javascript, views

i have a script for dealing with node images hover

```
(function ($) {
    $(function(){

    $('.node-photos-teaser').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass('photos-hover');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('photos-hover');
    });     


});
})(jQuery);
```

when clicking on a node filter set by 'better_exposed_filters' using ajax, 
the POST drupal/views/ajax?field_tags_tid_1=4 is loaded and filter out nodes fine but the JQuery behaviour is working nomore.

Ajax breaks jquery

Any help?

Comment: Read through [Managing Javascript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), you need to use Behaviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Clive answer i have solved out the problem embedding to my theme script file :

```
 Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFilters = {
    attach: function(context) {  }}
```

now having:

```
 (function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFilters = {
        attach: function(context) {         

    $('.node-photos-teaser').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass('photos-hover');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('photos-hover');
    });


        }}
})(jQuery);
```

renders compatible the JQuery from my theme with ajax from betterExposedFilter module

Comment: Hello @matoeil . can you plz tell me how can I do this without using better-exposed filters in Drupal 8