# Hide Specific block when search is performed with Expose Filters in Drupal 8.8

Tags: views

I have made a custom view which will show Results based on the selected expose filters.

I can access that VIEW on my local machine as:
http://drupal881/home

On leftside bar, I have some filters and when I select any filter it will display results with ajax on the same page.Above Search results I have another BLOCK. I want to hide that block so that expose filter results will be seen on top.

What is the correct way to do this. Need help please.

Comment: Views uses a specific Ajax response, in which you can add your own Ajax commands to manipulate the browser DOM in an event subscriber, see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/282086/47547

Comment: Its quite long and complicated. No other easy way?

Comment: It's a simple module with the two files you see in the example for the Ajax solution, and an Ajax command like this: `$response->addCommand(new CssCommand('.block-foo', ['display' => 'none']));`

Comment: I got a decent solution at this link: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/jquery-script-on-view-not-working-when-filtering-with-ajax-on-better-exposed/129643#129643. I made my custom js file and attach it with my theme. But the code not fires when I select any option from Select Box. Can you please take a look?

Comment: This is a different approach. IMHO the server-side PHP solution I've proposed is the better one, because Ajax is a server-side technology.

Comment: Yes I will implement this also. In the above one the code cannot run on exposedfilters only. whereas in Behaviours it is mentioned: Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFilters